How do I use CSS with a Gtk::DropDown widget?
I can't find the right CSS selector for coloring the main background area of a Gtkmm4 DropDown widget. dropdown has little effect as this widget is filled with child widgets which cover most (if not all) of its area; the same goes for popover which only shows a thin border around the dropdown menu.
I've tried the following.
dropdown: has little effect as it is filled with other widgets,
button: background colour of the main widget before activating,
popover: shows a thin border around the dropdown menu,
entry: effects the search box, if present,
label: effects the text in the dropdown menu and main top widget, not the surrounding area,
box: effects to the right of the labels,
listview: almost entirely covered by list items,
listview row and scrolledwindow: these cover most of the dropdown menu, but there are still gaps above and below, also
window, listbox, menu, popovermenu, popover.background, frame, grid.
Still I have my desktop theme's default grey below the list and around the search box. What underlying widget is occupying this space?
